# Spring cron expression for every day two times

Tags: spring, cron

I have following spring job to run every day two times please check my following cron express is that correct to trigger every day two times.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 24/12 * ? *")
public void demoService()
{

}
```

I tried the above expression, but this didn't work. What's wrong here?

Comment: Use expression "0 0 12,0 1/1 * ? *" and you can find next occurance on  [link] http://www.cronmaker.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

> 0 0 0/12 * * ?

which means every 12 hours.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/12 * * ?")
public void demoService()
{

}
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: Can we schedule one at 6am and one at 4pm only ??